# Are method entries and exits in NodeJS/V8 traceable through debugging APIs?

Tags: node.js, debugging, events, v8, trace

I'd like to know if it's possible to trace method entries and exits in NodeJS/V8.

**Context**

I know that NodeJS has some profiling options for Heap statistics and CPU usage.
However I'm not interested in those. I'm interested in method calls only.

For reference, what I'm looking for is something similar to what Java has in place [for methods](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/jdk.jdi/com/sun/jdi/event/MethodEntryEvent.html). Available through the Java Debugging Interface in the JDK.

**Already attempted**

I tried digging through the V8 documentation and NodeJS documentation.

For V8, all I could find was the capability to trace and output a `v8_trace.json`. Without a reference what's actually in the trace-file. Method entries? Exits? No clue. Also found no reference about its contents in the v8 github repo.

For NodeJS, I found the capability to start a process with `--inspect` which would alter the start-up command which I'd prefer not to do. Just in case I looked through the debugger documentation and I found no reference for any types of events it might catch.
I did find a reference for Trace Events. However, that part of the API seems to only concern how to start NodeJS in trace-enabled mode and which trace-categories are enabled. 
It does not specify any events that might be caught, where traces are stored nor their contents.

I'd appreciate any help you may be able to give me.

Answer (score 0):

V8 has a `--trace` flag, which will trace all function entries and returns. (Be prepared for *lots* of output on non-trivial programs!)

If you want more fine-grained control, then you can set breakpoints. Chrome DevTools provides a ready-to-use user interface for that; or you can use the inspector protocol to build your own integration.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but the --trace writes to a file correct? What I'm looking for is more like a temporary hook where I can catch method entry and exit-events. I don't necessarily need control. Just raw data from method calls.

Comment: No, `--trace` writes to stdout. There is no programmatic hook AFAIK.